# Kotlin: Merge Multiple Lists then ordering Interleaved merge list

Tags: list, sorting, kotlin, interleave

I have class `CatalogProduct(id: String, name: String)` to declare a product

I have two list below:

```
val newestCatalogProductList = mutableListOf<CatalogProduct>()
newestCatalogProductList.add(CatalogProduct("A1", "Apple"))
newestCatalogProductList.add(CatalogProduct("A2", "Banana"))
newestCatalogProductList.add(CatalogProduct("A3", "Orange"))
newestCatalogProductList.add(CatalogProduct("A4", "Pineapple"))

val popularCatalogProductList = mutableListOf<CatalogProduct>()
popularCatalogProductList.add(CatalogProduct("A5", "Milk"))
popularCatalogProductList.add(CatalogProduct("A6", "Sugar"))
popularCatalogProductList.add(CatalogProduct("A7", "Salt"))
popularCatalogProductList.add(CatalogProduct("A8", "Sand"))
```

I merged two list successfully by code below:

```
newestCatalogProductList.union(popularCatalogProductList)
```

But, i can not ordering interleaved merged list as expect:

```
CatalogProduct("A1", "Apple")
CatalogProduct("A5", "Milk")
CatalogProduct("A2", "Banana")
CatalogProduct("A6", "Sugar")
CatalogProduct("A3", "Orange")
CatalogProduct("A7", "Salt")
CatalogProduct("A4", "Pineapple")
CatalogProduct("A8", "Sand")
```

I'm begin study Kotlin. Please help me if you can explain or make example or give me reference link. So I thank you.

Comment: Create a new empty mutable list. Loop from 0 to the size of lists (assuming they have the same size). For each index, add to the new list the element from the two lists at that index.

Answer (score 3):

You can zip the lists to pair up items with the same index as lists of two items, and then flatten them:

```
val interleaved = newestCatalogProductList.zip(popularCatalogProductList) { a, b -> listOf(a, b) }
    .flatten()
```

If one of the lists might be longer you probably want to keep the remaining items of the longer list. In that case you might manually zip the items this way:

```
val interleaved2 = mutableListOf<CatalogProduct>()
val first = newestCatalogProductList.iterator()
val second = popularCatalogProductList.iterator()
while (interleaved2.size < newestCatalogProductList.size + popularCatalogProductList.size){
    if (first.hasNext()) interleaved2.add(first.next())
    if (second.hasNext()) interleaved2.add(second.next())
}
```

Comment: I understand, really really thanks Tenfour04. You're my hero. Thanks master.