# Kotlin: Merging pre-sorted sequences into a sorted sequence

Tags: sorting, kotlin, sequence

In Kotlin 1.4, I have a `Sequence` of `Sequence`s. The items in the inner Sequences are **already sorted** by one of their properties (`id`).

I want to merge them into one `Sequence` which would also be sorted by the same property.

It's quite trivial algorithm (always taking the smallest of the next items from all sequences).
But I was wondering:

Does Kotlin standard library have a stateless sequence merging operation for pre-sorted `Sequence`s?  Something like `Sequence<Sequence<T>>.flattenSorted(c: Comparator)` or so.

**Edit:**

As some have correctly assumed from the context, I am not looking for `flattenSorted()`, which is stateful, does not leverage the pre-sort, and for, say, 100 sequences of 1_000_000 elements, it wouldn't perform too well. I've reworded the question.

Comment: [Similar question, for List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000336/kotlin-merge-multiple-lists-then-ordering-interleaved-merge-list)

Comment: "It's quite trivial algorithm" what's your implementation? What if the sequences are `(1, 5, 7)` and `(2, 3, 4)`?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, not sure what you mean, by "What if the sequecnes are..." My implementation is below, and as you see, the algorithm is really trivial, the non-trivial part is to handle the iterators properly.

Comment: I was thinking that you meant it would do multiple passes, resulting in something like `(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7)`, but now I understood that you want to compare all the sequences every time you take an element.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, not all sequences, just their "next" element.

Comment: Maybe a sequence for the outer layer is not the best choice, because you need to use the sequence unsequentially.

Comment: Sequences are evaluated lazily, so until you terminate them into a target collection, no "pre-sorting" is actually performed on any of sequence items. Then (in case I've got you right) you just need to `sequenceOfSequences.flatten().sortedWith(/* comparator */).toList()`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko, the sequences are already sorted. They are results of 3 DB queries sorted by an index. That's what I meant by `I have a Sequence of Sequences of items sorted by ...`. But I have reworded it to be clearer.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004830/430128) by @Ondra Žižka however this variant is IMO easier to grok and use, because:

1. The type of the comparator passed in to the method is not affected by the implementation details i.e. comparing `Map.Entry<Iterator<T>, T>` rather than just the relevant value `T`.
2. It uses the `sequence` [builder](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence.html) to yield values into the returned sequence cleanly.
3. Other minor changes to improve readability.

```
fun <T> List<Sequence<T>>.mergeSorted(comparator: Comparator<T>): Sequence<T> {
  val iteratorToCurrentValues = map { it.iterator() }
    .filter { it.hasNext() }
    .associateWith { it.next() }
    .toMutableMap()

  val c: Comparator<Map.Entry<Iterator<T>, T>> = Comparator.comparing({ it.value }, comparator)

  return sequence {
    while (iteratorToCurrentValues.isNotEmpty()) {
      val smallestEntry = iteratorToCurrentValues.minWithOrNull(c)!!

      yield(smallestEntry.value)

      if (!smallestEntry.key.hasNext())
        iteratorToCurrentValues.remove(smallestEntry.key)
      else
        iteratorToCurrentValues[smallestEntry.key] = smallestEntry.key.next()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing such, I've implemented this, for X `Sequence`s, needing just a `Map` of the size X, and running in O(n).

```
fun <T> Sequence<Sequence<T>>.mergeSorted(comparator: Comparator<Map.Entry<Iterator<T>, T>>): Sequence<T> {

    // A map of iterators to their next value.
    val nexts = this
        .map { it.iterator() }
        .filter { it.hasNext() }
        .associateBy({it}, { it.next() }
    ).toMutableMap()
   
    return object : Sequence<T> {
        override fun iterator() = object : Iterator<T> {
            override fun hasNext() = nexts.isNotEmpty()

            override fun next(): T {
                val smallest = nexts.minWithOrNull(comparator)
                if (smallest == null)
                    throw NoSuchElementException("No more items. Did you forget to call hasNext()?")

                val toReturn = smallest.value
                if (!smallest.key.hasNext())   // This source is depleted.
                    nexts.remove(smallest.key)
                else
                    nexts[smallest.key] = smallest.key.next()
                
                return toReturn
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm I assume you are looking for is the **linear-time merge step** of [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

```kotlin
fun <E : Comparable<E>> mergeSeq(a_ : Sequence<E>, b_: Sequence<E>): Sequence<E> {
    val l = mutableListOf<E>()
    var a = a_
    var b = b_
    var a_head = a.firstOrNull()
    var b_head = b.firstOrNull()
    while (a_head != null && b_head != null) {
        if (a_head < b_head) {
            l.add(a_head)
            a = a.drop(1)
            a_head = a.firstOrNull()
        } else {
            l.add(b_head)
            b = b.drop(1)
            b_head = b.firstOrNull()
        }
    }
    return l.asSequence() + a + b
}

fun main() {
    val a = sequenceOf(1, 5, 7)
    val b = sequenceOf(2, 3, 9)
    println(mergeSeq(a, b).toList())
}
```

I wrote this implementation which does precisely that. Note the line `var a = a_` is needed because we function parameters are all `val` in Kotlin, and we cannot re-assign to `val`. The object you are passing would also need to implement `compareTo` so the line `a_head < b_head` works.

This also only merges 2 sequences, not n of them, for this you just repeatedly apply this function, e.g. as a fold/reduce:

```kotlin
fun <E : Comparable<E>> mergeSeqList(l : List<Sequence<E>>): Sequence<E> =
        l.fold(sequenceOf(), ::mergeSeq)
```

Comment: Nice, but this is not sorting a sequence of sequences, but 2 sequences, and applying it repeatedly is not too practical - what if I have 1000 of sequences?

Comment: It has a part at the bottom for a `List<Sequence<E>>`, which you can easily change to a `Sequence<Sequence<E>>`.

Comment: My solution would merge `m` sequences of length `k` in time `O(m^2 k)` which is worse than if you did it in binary fashion (as mergesort does), which is `O(m log m k)`. But I suggest trying my solution first to see if it handles your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this works but...

What if you first create a sorted set with a comparator and then keep adding all sub-sequences to this set?

Comparator should handle the case when both id's are equal - either remove one item or compare against some other field.